# FlatList not showing data correctly after data changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting the data from the database and show it in a FlatList. Whenever I add or remove something from the data the data isn't showing correctly in the FlatList.
Whenever I remove something it shows an empty list.
Whenever I add something it only shows the newly added data - nothing else.
[image: Left: Initial, Middle: New Added, Right: Data deleted]

I'm using firebase realtime database and use the data I get as follows:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/wordlists/${editKey}`).on('value', snap => {
    if (snap.val() !== null) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        const val = snap.val().words;
        const data = [];
        Object.keys(val).forEach(key => {
            data.push({ key, word: val[key].word });
        })
        setWords(data);
        // setWords([...data]) doesn't work either.
    }
})
```

My Flatlist looks like this:

```
<FlatList 
    data={words}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.key}
    extraData={words}
/>
```

When I console.log() the data I always get the data I want to show but the FlatList just won't show it correctly.

It also doesn't work when I use the spread-operator and/or extraData.

Because someone asked for it here is the entire file (I left out the styling and the imports)

```js
const EditList = ({ editKey }) => {

    const [wordlist, setWordlist] = useState(0);
    const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);
    const [words, setWords] = useState([]);
    const [wordLoading, setWordLoading] = useState({ loading: false });
    const [loading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [btnLoading, setBtnLoading] = useState(false);
    const [word, setWord] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (editKey !== 0) {
            setIsLoading(true);
            firebase.database().ref(`/wordlists/${editKey}`).on('value', snap => {
                if (snap.val() !== null) {
                    setIsLoading(false);
                    setWordlist({...snap.val()});
                    const val = snap.val().words;
                    const data = [];
                    Object.keys(val).forEach(key => {
                        data.push({ key, word: val[key].word });
                    })
                    setWords([...data]);
                    setRefresh(!refresh);
                    console.log(data, 'DATA');
                }
            })
        }
    }, [editKey])

    const onAdd = () => {
        setBtnLoading(true);
        firebase.database().ref(`/wordlists/${editKey}/words`).push({ word })
        .then(() => {
            setBtnLoading(false);
            setWord('');
            setRefresh(!refresh);
        })
    }

    const onDelete = (key) => {
        setWordLoading({ key, loading: true });
        firebase.database().ref(`/wordlists/${editKey}/words/${key}`).remove().then(() => {
            setWordLoading({ loading: false });
            setRefresh(!refresh);
        });
    }

    const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <ItemWrapper>
            <ItemWord>{ item.word }</ItemWord>
            <DeleteView onPress={() => onDelete(item.key)}>
                { wordLoading.loading && wordLoading.key === item.key ?
                    <ActivityIndicator size="small" /> :
                    <DIcon name="trash-2" size={24} />
                }
            </DeleteView>
        </ItemWrapper>
    )

    const createData = (words) => {
        const data = [];
        if (typeof words !== 'undefined') {
            Object.keys(words).forEach(key => {
                const obj = { key, word: words[key].word };
                data.push(obj);
            })
        }
        console.log(data, 'DATADATADATA');
        return data;
    }

    if (editKey === 0) {
        return (
            <NokeyWrapper>
                <NoKeyText>No list selected...</NoKeyText>
            </NokeyWrapper>
        )
    }
    if (loading) {
        return (
            <NokeyWrapper>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
            </NokeyWrapper>
        )
    }
    return (
        <Wrapper 
            behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"} 
            keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === 'ios' && 180}
        >
            <WordListName>{wordlist.listName}</WordListName>
            <FlatListWrapper>
                <FlatList 
                    data={words}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.key}
                    //extraData={refresh}
                    extraData={words}
                />
            </FlatListWrapper>
            <AddWordWrapper>
                <SInput value={word} onChangeText={(text) => setWord(text)} />
                <Button onPress={() => onAdd()} loading={btnLoading}>
                    <Feather name="plus" size={24} color="black" />
                </Button>
            </AddWordWrapper>
        </Wrapper>
    )
};

export default EditList;
```

Comment: try this - `setWords([...data]);`

Comment: How do you update the `words` array? make sure you're not mutating it. And also try using `extraData` prop of the `Flatlist`

Comment: @SarunUK thanks for your comment. I already tried that and tried again but it still shows the same thing.

Comment: @Yasmin I already tried that. Using extraData doesn't help. I'm updating the array via setWords(data). I also tried using the spread operator like Sarun suggested ( setWords([...data])) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I really tried a lot already. I had similar problems like this in the past and I know it usually has something to do with mutating the state. Therefore I tried to use the spread operator but still the problem occurs.

Comment: can you show the whole code?

Comment: @UkeshShrestha I added almost the entire Code to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more tries I found out the problem was somewhere else. Somehow using 'flex: 1' on my  in my renderItem() was causing this issue. I actually found this issue also on github: [GitHub React Native issues](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15990#issuecomment-437649201)

So after removing 'flex: 1' from the element everything was showing as expected.

```
// before
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <ItemWrapper style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: row }}>
        <ItemWord>{ item.word }</ItemWord>
    </ItemWrapper>
)

// after
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <ItemWrapper style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <ItemWord>{ item.word }</ItemWord>
    </ItemWrapper>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

u need to useRef for this instance because the new 'words' is not inside the .on('value') call.

```
 const [words, _setWords] = useState([]);
 const wordRef = useRef(words)


 //function to update both wordRef and words state
 const setWords = (word) => {
        
      wordRef = word
      _setWords(word)
 } 



useEffect(() => {

if (editKey !== 0) {
    setIsLoading(true);
    let data = wordRef   //create a temp data variable
    firebase.database().ref(`/wordlists/${editKey}`).on('value', snap => {
        if (snap.val() !== null) {
            setIsLoading(false);                 
            setWordlist({...snap.val()});
            const val = snap.val().words;

            Object.keys(val).forEach(key => {
                data.push({ key, word: val[key].word });
            })
            setWords(data);
            setRefresh(!refresh);
            console.log(data, 'DATA');
        }
    })

    return () => firebase.database().ref(`/wordlists/${editKey}`).off('value') // <-- need to turn it off.
}
}, [editKey, wordRef])
```

You probably need to change setRefresh etc with the same method if they are not refreshing.